# Django - Custom backwards relation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-key-relationship

An **Setting** belongs to an **Office**. Each time a Setting is updated, I make a new entry in the database, passing the old Setting to active=False and the new Setting to active=true. So each office has only one active setting at a time (i'm doing this because I wan't to keep track of old settings).

Now what I need is a way to access this setting via the Office object.
At the moment I am accessing it with the backwards relation **office.setting_set**.

I'm using Django-Rest-Framework so I need a field that is serializable.
In my serializer, I call: office.setting_set. In regular django I could probably do office.setting_set.filter(active=True) but I can't do so in a serializer...

The ideal would be a custom model field that I would call something like:

```
office.active_setting
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: "the problem with this is that I can't filter on the active=True field" - why not? Why not `office.setting_set.filter(active=True)`?

Comment: Sorry didn't explain it well in the first place. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#model-methods) for this. The method would likely be something similar to the following:

```
def active_setting(self):
    return self.setting_set.get(active=True)
```